# Finder dying when Mac wakes from sleep

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, finder

I have this persisting issue where when I put my Mac (Snow Leopard) to sleep on my MacBook, whenever I wake the Mac, everything is fine besides the Finder.

The Finder does not open up, none of the folders I click on (via desktop) open up, so I end up killing my Finder via Activity Monitor and it then resets my folder settings (I have snap to grid and large icons for example).

What's going on and why is it doing this?

Comment: Run "sudo spindump Finder" next time this happens and post the resulting text file. Then anyone who knows Mac OS X internals should be able to give you an idea of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks mate,see answer below. If it doesnt work ill psot as per your instructions

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have any other extensions loaded and also if it always occurs or only when specific applications are running. Often this can be caused by an app that doesn't like going to sleep. :)